# Web API return paging status and ienumerable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am developing web api to broadcast huge data via paging. I am using apicontroller. While returning, I have to return paging status like current page, total pages, total number of records, etc. And with it the set of records for example 10000 rows.

```
public IEnumerable<object> Get(){

  HttpContext.Current..Response.Headers.Add("name", "responseMsg");
  return ....
}
```

Here I am using HttpContext to add header msg which is throwing error that api is not reachable. What could be the other way around to get the same result?

Comment: What is the version of .net ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your headers to Response like this:

```
Response.Headers.Add("X-Total-Count", "xxx");
```

Comment: It is same as I mentioned. It is throwing error. Is there any other way ?

Comment: This is working at least for .net core 3, I suspect his .net version is different.